# Google Closure Compiler type annotations for array

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

While playing around with Google Closure Compiler, I found a case where I couldn't force the compiler to give a warning for a wrong variable type. I used the following sample:

```
/** @typedef ({name: string, token: string}) */
var pendingItem;

/** @type (Array.<pendingItem>) */
var pending = [];

// NOTICE: the token is intentionally misspelled as "toke" to cause a warning
var dummyItem = {
  name: 'NameHere',
  toke: 'SomeToken' 
};

// This should cause a warning, because of the 
// type mismatch (toke instead of token)
pending.push(dummyItem);

// Do something useful so that the whole code wouldn't be optimized to 0 bytes
alert(pending.length);
```

And it compiles perfectly, instead of giving the expected type warning. But if you use:

```
pending[1] = {
  name: 'Second Name',
  toke: 'Second Token'
}
```

You get the expected type mismatch warning.

I understand that it's probably because `push` doesn't have type-checking defined, since it's a built-in function. It would be expected that defining `pending` as an array of `pendingItem` would force it, but it doesn't by default.

The question is whether and how is it possible to add type checking to already defined functions such as `push`, so that it would give a warning in the example above. I also understand that one way to achieve a similar result would be to add `/** @type {pendingItem} */` before `dummyItem` to force the type, but for educational purposes, I would like to know about adding type checking to functions like `push` (or maybe stricter definition of `pending` itself).

Also could somebody explain what is the logic behind renaming object properties? If you compile the above example, it wouldn't rename `dummyItem`'s property `name`, but it would rename `token` to `a`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To force type checking on `push`, it has to be redefined in code with the correct type. Note that using object literal notation, you have to define the types by using `@type` instead of `@param`, because we are assigning the function to a object's parameter, not defining a normal function. In this case it would be the following:

```
/** @type {function(pendingItem)} */
pending.push = function(item) {
  Array.prototype.push.call(pending, item);
};
```

Now when trying to compile the following:

```
// Still an intentionally misspelled "toke"
var dummyItem = {
  name: 'NameHere',
  toke: 'SomeToken' 
};

// First warning
pending.push(dummyItem);

// Second warning
pending[1] = {
  name: 'Second name',
  toke: 'Second Token'
};
```

Then both will generate a type mismatch warning, like expected.

Thought that it might be useful to somebody in the future.