# With Closure Compiler what are the benefits of Array<T> annotation vs. just Array?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, google-closure, typechecking

I expected Closure Compiler to warn on all the lines below, but only 3) shows up as a problem.  [Type Checking Array Contents with Closure-Compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18762608/type-checking-array-contents-with-closure-compiler) touches on this same point, but my question is, given these limitations, what benefits are realized from annotating `Array<T>` vs `Array`?  I feel like it's a false sense of security.

```
// ==ClosureCompiler==
// @compilation_level SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS
// @output_file_name default.js
// @warning_level VERBOSE
// ==/ClosureCompiler==

/** @type {!Array<!string>} */
var xs = [];
xs.push(42);       // 1) no warning
xs.push(null);     // 2) no warning
xs = 'foo'         // 3) warns - found: string, required: Array<string>
xs = [1,2,3];      // 4) no warning
```

Quick edit: You can play around with this code at http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/

Comment: Javascript has no type limitation. You can `var xs = true;` then `xs++;` Unless some other interpretor has a limitation, you will not have security.... however, most systems will inform you if you do unexpected operations. As far as I can tell, its the only advantage.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is because the [externs definition for Array.prototype.push](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/master/externs/es3.js#L499) is not quite correct. If you remove the `@this` type then you should get the expected errors. Presumably the `{length: number}` part was added for some reason though, so removing it may break some existing code somewhere.

Comment: This is true.  The Array.prototype methods are generic, they can accept any "array-like" object (NodeList, TypedArray, Arguments, etc).  However, this is will be fixed when Array implements IArrayLike (which we introduced in the last release).   Then rather than `{length:number}|Array<T>` it will simply be `IArrayLike<T>`, which will work as we want.

Comment: @John Thanks for this. What about the `xs = [1,2,3];` case above?  `xs` is explicitly `Array<string>` and `[1,2,3]` seems at worst to be inferred as  `Array<*>`.  Seems like it should warn?

Comment: That is a bit different, that is simply that the object literal is inferred as "Array<?>" and that changes in the compilers "new type inference".

Answer (score 0):

You'll gain the same benefits of generics like other static languages.
Lets say that you want to create an array of strings and later sort them using the their length.

```
var arr = [];    
arr.sort(function(a, b) { return a.length - b.length; });
```

If you annotate the array as `Array` then you will be able to add a number to the array and closure compiler will not complain.
Eventually you will face an exception, because a number does not have a length property.
If you will annotate the array as array of strings `Array<string>` then you will make sure that the length property will exists and that no one will be able to insert any other type other than a string.

I don't why you get no compilation errors with string, but if you try it with number you'll get different compilation results.

```
// ==ClosureCompiler==
// @compilation_level SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS
// @output_file_name default.js
// @warning_level VERBOSE
// ==/ClosureCompiler==

/** @type {!Array<!number>} */
var xs = [];
xs.push(42);
console.log(xs[0].length);

=> 
Number of warnings: 1

JSC_INEXISTENT_PROPERTY: Property length never defined on Number at line 4 character 18
console.log(xs[0].length);
              ^
```

Comment: In my example above I annotate `xs` as `Array<string>` and am able to add non-strings to the array. `xs` retains the type `Array<string>` but now contains non-strings.  I *want* it to work the way you describe though :)

Comment: Are you using the advanced mode compilation?

Comment: I'm not in this example, no. But it doesn't appear to influence type checking, only how aggressively the code is minified/transformed. https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/compilation_levels

Comment: I was under the impression that the compiler issued warnings but did not provide that level of type safety (i.e. ensured that no non-conforming types were added)?